# getting PHP syntax error unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Tags: php, foreach, header

I am trying to make a foreach code that automatically makes my header for my site. The idea is that as I add more pages I can just add them to the array and it will auto update the header for me. Usually my foreach'es work but for the first time I am having trouble. I tried it two ways, both of which spat out the same error.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css" />
<?php
$page = array("index.php", "about.php");
$names = array("Home", "About")


foreach($names as $name){
    echo "<a href=$page> $name </a>";
}

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css" />
<?php
$page = array("index.php", "about.php");
$names = array("Home", "About")

foreach($page as $pages){
    foreach($names as $name){
        echo "<a href=$pages> $name </a>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: As always, you're missing a semi-colon.

Comment: ... `$names = array("Home", "About")` <= John means there.

Comment: @JohnConde See, our comments are worth the paper they were written on. Comments *ignored*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- at least no trees where harmed.

Comment: @JohnConde Thank the good Lord for that.

Comment: Love that @John Conde. Been writing so much swift I forgot what a semi-colon looked like :-)

Answer (score 16):

Usually when PHP returns "unexpected" it means the thing before it is not quite right, as with this case:

You have `$names = array("Home", "About")` <-- no semi colon to end the line, and so the next line `foreach` is *unexpected*, as it was "expecting" a `;`

And looks like you've copy/pasted the mistake (missing semi colon) to other places in your code too

Comment: I did not even realize that, thank you. It's always the little things.

Answer (score 6):

when php return error "unexpected" it line # xxx , then it mean you missing semi colon ";" it line #  xxx-1  mean above line of xxx line

so in your case your are missing semi color ";" above foreach loop

```
$names = array("Home", "About")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with comments to explain:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
$page = array("index.php", "about.php");
$names = array("Home", "About"); // Fixed semicolon

// Added the key before the foreach. This allows us to reference which number in we are.
foreach($names as $key => $name)
{
    // Added the key to the page array variable to specify the right page.
    echo "<a href=".$page[$key].">".$name."</a>";
}?>
</body>
```

To further simplify using array keys, try this:

```
<?php
// Define page names as key and url as value.
$pages = array("Home" => "index.php", "About" => "about.php");

// Added the key before the foreach as url this time
foreach($pages as $name => $url)
{
    // Added the key to the page array variable to specify the right page.
    echo "<a href=".$url.">".$name."</a>";
}?>
```

Comment: You should note that they will have to make sure those two arrays are in tandem (if you're going to *improve* their code for them, then ideally this would be in one array, with key as name and value as href, or whatever)

Comment: Agreed on the tandem arrays, adjusting my answer. However, this would not output a number in the anchor, it'd output the value of the $names array, which is a string... either Home or About.

Comment: Yeah getting tired, sorry - it would match the `$pages` value from the loop's `$names` key if they are in tandem.